# Creating an "untransparent" squares

Tags: algorithm

I'm writing a program that prints the circumference of squares to the screen according to coordinates and length of a side given by the user for each square.

The squares should be on top of each other if they overlap so that the bottom one is being hidden by the top one.

The order of the squares is set according to the order they were entered to the program (First is bottom).

For example:

&&&&
&    &
&    &$$$
&&&&   $
    $      $
    $      $
    $$$$$

The best algorithm I came up with is with time complexity of O(n^2) for each square.

Any suggestion for how to make the squares "untransparent"?

Comment: The painters algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painters_algorithm) handles this.

Comment: @AndyG: That's probably exactly what the OP means by his `O(n^2)` algorithm.

Comment: @AndreyT: Constructing a BSP in the general case is O(n^2), but for orthogonal geometry, Paterson and Yao showed it to be O(n sqrt n )

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/019667749290007Y

Comment: @AndyG: Firstly, I don't see what it has to do with BSPs. The whole idea of "painter's algorithm" is that you simply rasterize things from back to front and everything comes out properly without any BSPs. Secondly, in any raster algorithm the amount of work needed is guaranteed to be `O(n^2)` simply because you have to fill `O(n^2)` pixels per square. You can optimize it, but it will not change anything asymptotically.

Comment: @AndreyT What I meant is that a painter's algorithm paints back to front. Therefore, it needs an ordering. A BSP gives such an ordering, accounting for the case off cyclic overlap. In OP's case, a naive painter's algorithm can probably work, as the ordering is already specified by input, so there won't be any cyclic overlap.

Comment: @AndyG: Yes, but the OP's issue is that he spends `O(n^2)` *per square*. I.e. the problem is that he has to render the entire square  (`n^2` pixels) to erase the invisible previous of the previous squares. That's how a full-blown painter's algorithm works. However, his problem is more "simple": he's probably rendering "white squares with black edges on white background". In such cases it is tempting to avoid rasterization entirely and just draw the black edges - the visible portions of them. This will be more efficient as long as we know which portions are visible and which are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `O(n^2)` algorithm you mention is probably the classic "painter's algorithm", in which you simply render ("rasterize") the squares one after another from the bottom ones to the top ones. This is a perfectly good algorithm, widely used in computer graphics. However, any "raster" algorithm will have the same time complexity of `O(n^2)` per square.

But if you want an asymptotically faster algorithm, you have to look for a "vector" algorithm, i.e. the algorithm that works with  the *edges* of the squares, but does not waste time processing their interiors. One way to build such an algorithm is to pre-calculate the final visible edge layout in vector form and then draw only the visible edges on the screen.

To implement something like that each square has to be initially represented by a set of four edges. Then a single pass of *sweep-line* algorithm will eliminate the invisible edges. And then you can render the remaining visible edges on the screen. This algorithm will be a lot more complex than "painter's algorithm", since you will have to implement the sweeping and edge elimination logic. But for this particular problem (especially considering that it deals with orthogonal geometry) it is not at all that difficult.

P.S. One critical point here is that the latter approach can only work if all the squares are known in advance, i.e it is only applicable to an off-line problem. If you are dealing with an on-line problem, i.e. you have to draw the squares immediately as they are received from the input, not knowing all of them in advance, then in general case there's no reason to attempt to improve anything here. Just use the painter's algorithm.

Comment: Can you please specify a bit more about vector form and sweep-line algorithm? I'm not familiar with either.

Comment: @David Tzoor: "Sweep line" is an approach used to build various vector algorithms, i.e. algorithms that, say, process polygons specified as sets of edges. This is a rather extensive topic, which is too broad to be covered in a single answer here. Do a search on "sweep line algorithm" on the Net, and you will find plenty of information. Any book on computation geometry will also describe that approach.

Comment: In any case, the idea in this case is to clip away the invisible portions of edges in advance. Sweep line works very well for that purpose, but other approaches can probably be used as well.